# How does the Func delegate work when it requires an interface as a parameter?

Tags: c#, .net

Specifically, I'm looking at this line of code from Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions.cs:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddScoped<TService>(this IServiceCollection services, Func<IServiceProvider, TService> implementationFactory) where TService : class;
```

An example using this method would be:

```
services.AddScoped<ICustomService>(sp => new CustomService(
    sp.GetRequiredService<IAnotherCustomService>(), "Param1", "Param2"));
```

I understand how the Func delegate and lambda expressions work, but I'm not understanding how `IServiceProvider` is being initialized behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IServiceProvider` is not being initialized behind the scenes at this point in time. The framework is merely capturing the passed-in delegate and saving it for a later time, when it has an IServiceProvider instance and needs to generate an `ICustomService`.

There is nothing specific to interfaces happening here. The same principle would apply with any argument type for a delegate.

```
// This captures the delegate in a variable
Func<int, string> f = i => i.ToString();

// This invokes the delegate with an instance of an `int`
f(1);
f(2);
```